# Why doesn't my struct code work?

Tags: struct, go

```
package app

type ConfigSet struct {
    installed bool
}

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

func init() {
    config := ConfigSet{}

    // -------------------------------------- //
    //             CONFIGURATION              //
    // -------------------------------------- //

    // Change to "true" after configuration is done!
    config.installed = false

    // -------------------------------------- //
    //           END CONFIGURATION            //
    // -------------------------------------- //

    http.HandleFunc("/", index)
    http.HandleFunc("/index.php", index)
}

func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if config.installed == false {
        w.Header().Set("Location", "/install/")
        return
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why this doesn't work. The error I get is:

```
2012/05/21 13:22:01 go-app-builder: Failed parsing input (1 error)
2012/05/21 13:22:01 /root/TravianGAE/app/app.go:7:1: expected declaration, found 'import'
```

I don't understand, am I supposed to declare anything there?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put your `import` first, before the `type`.

Comment: Seems to be working. Go is definitely harder than I initially thought.

Comment: It's not so difficult; I'd suggest trying to develop things locally first, then GAE. You'll get a better feel for things.